# Html.BeginForm in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, razor-components

When working with MVC you can use

```
@using (Html.Beginform("", ""))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary("true")
}
```

To show an error message from the controller.

In one of my controllers I have this code

```
Game existingGame = context.Games.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Title == game.Title.ToLower());
                if(existingGame != null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This Game already exist");
                }
                else if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    context.Add(game);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return game.Id;
                }
                return Ok();
```

This code work, cause I cant add a second game with the same name.
But how do I display the error message in a razor-component with blazor?

I tried the Html.Beginform but I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor, the equivalent of

```
@Using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary("true")
}
```

would be

```
<EditForm Model=@MyModel>
   <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>
```

If you're just moving to Blazor, I highly recommend going through the tutorials at: https://blazor-university.com/forms/ for advice specific to forms.

And check out the other tutorials at that site.